# My AWS VPN setup results in no traffic working when connecting

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, amazon-vpc

I have created a VPN to our VPC but when I connect to it from my machine, nothing works - neither Internet, nor can I reach VPN-internal endpoints.

I added public `dns-servers` and `split-tunnel=enabled` to the configuration.

The VPN is set to

```
`Client IPv4 CIDR 10.10.0.0/16`
```

An association has been added (line from AWS console):

```
cvpn-assoc-<id>     subnet-<id>    cvpn-endpoint-<id> ￼     Associated     sg-<id>
```

There are two authorization rules (one allowing everything until I get it working)

The route table looks like this (was automatically added via the assoc):

```
cvpn-endpoint-<id>  10.1.0.0/16 subnet-<id>  Nat      associate ￼    Active      Default Route
```

This RT is the only thing which looks odd. In the VPC, the subnet has a definition of `10.1.0.0/24` - but the automatic association sets it to `10.1.0.0/16`. But there's actually no way to set it to `10.1.0.0/24` in the routing table, doing so results in an error about the range being invalid.

I also tried creating the VPC with a client IP CIDR of `10.10.0.0/24` but then it errored saying it must at least be `/22`.

Comment: This belongs on [sf], not here.

Comment: Actually you are right. I crossposted this there https://serverfault.com/questions/1023049/my-aws-vpn-setup-results-in-no-traffic-working-when-connecting, and also finally found myself the problem...(at least part of it).